# Basic IF Statement Error for Last Modified tracking

Tags: vba, excel

I am a novice coder recently getting away from web-based coding and was having an error with my script. I already can tell that this is poorly scripted and was wondering if I could receive any help.

This script is simply supposed to set the equivalent offset cell to the current time and date after any of the cells in that range is changed. I believe my poor scripting is either causing a loop or miss-calculating information as excel crashes after the event fires.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("E5:E100")) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(0, 3) = Now()
        Target.Offset(0, -1) = Target.Offset(0, -1).Value + 1
    Else
        If Intersect(Target, Range("F5:F100")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        Target.Offset(0, 2) = Now()
        Target.Offset(0, -1) = Target.Offset(0, -1).Value + 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `If Intersect(Target, Range("E5:E100")) Is Nothing` as the criteria is checking that the target **doesn't** intersect your range. I'm going to assume, based on the Offsets you use that you're only actually interested in columns E and F.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False 'prevent event re-firing based on changes made by the event
If Not (Intersect(Target, Range("E5:F100")) Is Nothing) Then
    Target.Offset(0, (7 - Target.Column)) = Now()
    Target.Offset(0, -(Target.Column - 4)) = Target.Offset(0, -(Target.Column - 4)).Value + 1
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True 'allows event to fire again
End Sub
```

So to clarify, the above looks for changes in columns E or F (rows 5 to 100) and if there is one writes the date stamp to the same row in column G, and the counter to column D.

Comment: Basically, my goal for this is that I have two columns, "E5:E100" and "F5:F100". Whenever either of these columns is updated. I want this to reflect by updating a third column, (In this situation column H) with the current time and date that it was modified. The 2nd "Target.Offset(0, -1) = Target.Offset(0, -1).Value + 1" was my attempt at a "Iteration Tracker" for any time, this value changes. The Iteration progresses by one.

Comment: Oh. The issue is that Offset(0,-1) if fired due to a change to column F, is going to write to column E - which sounds like that might not be what you want?

Comment: You are right, I believe that was an oversight on my part when I first created the script.

Comment: I'll change the answer above to cater.

Comment: Thank you that appears to have solved everything. You extremely helpful. Thank you for putting up with a novice, Haha.

Answer (score 1):

You need to temprorarily stop the events from happening as you are changing the value on the sheet which then fires the event again and it continues to loop till excel crashes.

Put

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

At the beginning and make sure to add

```
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

At the end to turn them back on.

So:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E5:E100")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target.Offset(0, 3) = Now()
    Target.Offset(0, -1) = Target.Offset(0, -1).Value + 1
    Application.EnableEvents = True
Else
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F5:F100")) Is Nothing Then 
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target.Offset(0, 2) = Now()
    Target.Offset(0, -1) = Target.Offset(0, -1).Value + 1
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was extremely helpful. I believe that is not was I was going for. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: See edit for what you want based on your comment to CLR @DrewDicenso

Comment: As of this moment, i have re-worked my code based off both of your suggestion. I am currently attempting to find a Block If error happening in the first line.